# How to add some padding between a ListView and its footer?

Tags: application-development, qml

Consider the following QML snippet:

```
ListView {
    //...

    footer: Text {
        text: "Sample Text"
    }
}
```

This will display the text "Sample Text" directly at the bottom of the ListView. However, there is no space between the last item in the list and the text.

How do I add some spacing/padding? I've tried setting `anchors.top` and `anchors.topMargin` but all that does is give me the "Possible anchor loop detected on vertical anchor" warning. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you try my proposal? (Or are you looking for alternatives?)

Comment: @Sylvain: sorry, I forgot to reply. I tried your suggestion but still could not get it to work. I ended up using a transparent rectangle to add padding. I'm not at a computer at the moment, but when I am, I'll add a comment to your answer and explain what I ended up doing.

Comment: I tested it on 14.04 (if that matters). But thanks for your feedback. I'd really want to know what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the `ContactModel.qml` available in the SDK [example](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/QtQuick.ListView/#details).

To add some spacing between your footer and the last list element you can create a dedicated component for your footer and modify the layout the way you want inside it:

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

Item {
    width: 200
    height: 350

    ListView {
        width: 180; height: 200
        model: ContactModel {}
        delegate: Text {
            text: name + ": " + number
        }

        Component {
            id: myfooter
            Item {
                width: parent.width
                height: units.gu(3)
                Text {
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    text: "Sample Text"
                }
            }
        }

        footer: myfooter
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: [This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9241532/) is what I tried. The major difference is that I didn't specify a height for the footer component - I'd prefer not to hardcode a height value since it will cut off content if it is larger than the specified value.

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was creating a `Column` and inserting a `Rectangle` before the content I wanted to appear in the footer:

```
Rectangle {
    color: "transparent"
    width: parent.width
    height: units.gu(3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware of transparrent rectangles in fonts, they are just not assigned yet in that particulary font, other fonts might display special caracters or dingbats!

Have you tried the obvious (escape newline)

```
footer: Text {
    text: "\nSample Text"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bottomMargin` property of the `ListView` to add extra space at the end of the list. Please note that this property is inherited from the `Flickable`.
However, from a UX point of view, it seems that making footer same look like other regular items is a bad idea (generally).